Uploading Image from React Native Expo to Python API - File Size Issue
I'm using a React Native Expo setup to get an image from the library and post it to a Python API for uploading. The issue I'm facing is that while the image is successfully added and the file size is visible in the React Native app, when the Python API receives the request, the file size is reported as zero.
// Python API
app = FastAPI(max_upload_size=1024 * 1024 * 1024)

@app.post("/api/upload")
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
   try:
        # Save the file to disk
        file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file.filename)
        with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
            content = await file.read()
            f.write(content)
        return JSONResponse(content={'file': file.filename})
   except Exception as e:
        return JSONResponse(content={'error': str(e)}, status_code=500)

// React-Native with Expo
const uploadImage =  async () =>{
    try {
        if(selectedImageUri != null){
          console.log("Image uri: ", selectedImageUri) // Image uri:  ph://106E99A1-4F6A-45A2-B320-B0AD4A8E8473
          const result = await fetch(selectedImageUri)
          const blobData = await result.blob()

          let fileOfBlob = new File([blobData], 'upload.jpeg', { type: 'image/jpeg' });  
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', fileOfBlob); 

          // Send POST request with Axios
          const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/upload`, formData, {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" 
              },
            });         
          }
        } catch (error) {
        debugger;
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };



Why is the file size reported as zero in the Python API, even though the image is successfully added and the file size is visible in the React Native app? What could be the possible reasons for this issue, and how can I resolve it?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Does this answer your question? Related answers might be found here and here as well.

@Chris Unfortunately no, when I look at it I am sending the formdata similar,  except in my case I am getting blob using uri and creating a file, which seems to be working, like I mentioned api fails to send the actual file! I have tried using fetch on client and express as my server as well. Not sure where it is going wrong.
~thanks

Please have a look at this answer, this answer and this answer as well.
